# How to reload the same view if an error occurs in the logic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, xcode6

I'm new to iOS. I'm writing the login flow in an app. What I want to achieve is that if the login fails the same view is loaded with an error message populated in the error message label. So I update the error message label as follows:

```
-(void) showError:(NSString *)errorMessage{
    self.errorMessage.text = errorMessage;
}
```

the and if the login is successful the following method is called

```
-(void)loggedIn
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:nil];
}
```

to move on to the next view.

What is happening is, irrespective of whether the login fails or succeeds it moves on to the next view. 
What is the correct way to handle this?

```
- (IBAction)signInButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self loginWithUsername:self.username.text andPassword:self.password.text];

}

- (void) loginWithUsername : (NSString *)username andPassword:(NSString *)password {

    NSLog(@"Username is %@ , Password is %@ ", username , password);
    AuthenticationService *service =    [[AuthenticationService alloc] init];
    if([service authenticateWithUsername:username andPassword:password]){
    [self loggedIn];
    if (self.rememberMe) {
        [self storeLoginInformationWithUsername:username password:password];
    }

    }
    else {
           [self showError];
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't call `loggedIn` when you get a login error. Without seeing more code, it's difficult to help you debug this issue.

Comment: You are calling `loggedIn` irrespective of the outcome. first check the returned result from `authentication service` and execute accordingly

Comment: I'm calling loggedIn only if([service authenticateWithUsername:username andPassword:password]) returns a true

Answer (score 0):

The code looks simple logical.
I think that `[service authenticateWithUsername:username andPassword:password]` returns `YES` for some reasons. Just check logic of this method.

Comment: The function returns NO. But for some reason the programmatic segue is being overridden and the segue happens anyway. Could something be incorrect in the way I've set it up on the storyboard?

Comment: Post the code related to the mentioned method to see whats happening, if possible.

Comment: @Nandita Rao I don't think so, your code is very simple. 
So do i understand right? When logging failed, your text label updated with error message and then function `loggedIn` called?

And yes, as @ThXou said - you should post code of this method for better understanding

Comment: Btw, your method `showError:` requires NSString as parameter. But in your example you just do `[self showError];`. Is it a real code?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I had a segue from the SignIn button to the next view controller. I changed it. I created a segue from the first controller to the second one and solved my issue.